# Symfony2 doctrine passing a parameter on foreign key in findBy function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

i'm trying to load an entity passing a parameter to a foreign key which is the `inverse side`

i have this two entities

Ad

```
/**
 * Ad
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Ad")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Symarket\MarketBundle\Repository\AdRepository")
 */
class Ad 
{
     /**
     * @var AdImage
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AdImage", mappedBy="ad", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     */
     private $images;

     //...
}
```

AdImage

```
/**
 * AdImage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="AdImage")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Symarket\MarketBundle\Repository\AdImageRepository")
 */
class AdImage {

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adi_is_visible", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isVisible;

    /**
     * @var Ad
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ad", inversedBy="images", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="adi_ad_id", referencedColumnName="ad_id")
     */
    protected $ad;
}
```

now, by getting a `Ad` from the database i want to get ONLY the images which are `"isVisibile" => true`

how is this possible with queryBuilder?

what i tried so far with the findBy function is this

```
public function findById($adId) {
    $res = $this->findBy(array("id" => $adId, "isVisible" => true, "images" => array("isVisible" => true)));
    $ad = reset($res);

    return $ad;
}
```

and i got this error
    You cannot search for the association field 'Symarket\MarketBundle\Entity\Ad#images', because it is the inverse side of an association. Find methods only work on owning side associations.

then i tried this way with the querybuilder

```
public function findById($adId) {
    $res = $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('ad')
            ->leftJoin('ad.images', 'img')
            ->where('img.isVisible = :adVisible')
            ->andWhere('ad.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('adId', $adId)
            ->setParameter('imgVisible', true)
            ->getQuery();

    $ad = reset($res);

    return $ad;
}
```

and i get `NULL`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your attempted query with queryBuilder?

Comment: edited, ask if you need something more

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `reset()` on the query results. If you want a single result you should try `getSingleResult()` or `getOneOrNullResult()`. If you want only the first result in a query that produces more than one, you should use `getResult()` and handle the logic of only using the first in your controller. See [Doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats)

Comment: nice, thanks for the advice but this is not the main problem :)

Comment: Well I can't help you with a queryBuilder solution if you don't follow the documented use of that method.

Comment: I know how to use queryBuilder and i already used it successfully, i just don't know what's the best way to do what i asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for those who may encounter this problem here goes my solution:

```
public function findById($adId) {
    $ad = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT a, i from MarketBundle:Ad a LEFT JOIN a.images i with i.isVisible = :visible where a.id = :adId")
            ->setParameter("adId", $adId)
            ->setParameter("visible", true)->getSingleResult();

    return $ad;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the default repository for your AdImage entity. Consider this example:

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
// You said you already have the Ad entity instance you care about so just grabbing by id for demonstration purposes
$ad = $entityManager->getRepository('Ad')->findOneById(5);
$adImagesVisible = $entityManager->getRepository('AdImage')->findBy(array('isVisible' => true, 'ad' => $ad->getId()));
```

If you approach this from the entity on the "Many" side of the relationship you should be able to get what you want without having to write a custom DQL query.